# useEffect triggering when the component loads, and not when the state changes, as I have set it

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am trying to trigger my useEffect when I change `useState`, however, it only triggers once when the component loads (which I don't want at all) What's the issue with the code?

```
const [value, setValue] = useState('initial');
    useEffect(()=>{
        let url = "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json";
        let count = 30;
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/api/grabIt',
            data: {
                url: url,
                count: count
            }
        })
            .then(function (res) {
                console.log(res.data.response)
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error)
            });
    },[value]);
    
    return (
        <div className={styles.displayType}>
            <ButtonContainer/>
            <Button buttonColor={!!isDarkMode}
                    onClick={ () => setValue('triggered')}
            >FETCH</Button>
        </div>
    )
```

Comment: If you don't want the useEffect to be triggered when rendering the component, but only when the button is clicked, then I don't see why you would put it in a useEffect, and not just create a simple function to handle the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you're trying to achieve, you don't need an effect.
I'd handle the fetch from a function like this:

```
// simplified the example
const [value, setValue] = useState("initial");

const handleFetch = () => {
  setValue("triggered");
};

return (
  <div>
    <button onClick={handleFetch}>{value}</button>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

in your function useEffect you have set dependencies include `value`. This mean only call when you `value` changed. After you value is set `triggered`. It will never change, cause primitive value string 'triggered' === 'triggered'.

You may using boolean to trigger click. Example:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(false);
...
<Button buttonColor={!!isDarkMode}
        onClick={ () => setValue(!value)}
```